# Cannot create a connection between a UIImageView and the ViewController.h

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview

I cannot create a connection between the`UIImageView` and the ViewController.h.

When I try to type it up manually, and drag the line to the`UIImageView`, it doesn't highlight the`UIImageView`, and the connection is not made.
When I tried to connect it automatically, but the connection was also not made.
Can you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: You probably didn't set the class of `UIVIewController` in the `storyboard`

Comment: Do you mean IBOutlet? Are you using a storyboard?

Comment: check for that is there the same controller class to the ViewControllre and if yes then this often happens so simply quit the Xcode and restart it again it works and quit the simulator too

Comment: How do you set the class For the UIVewController in the storyboard?

Comment: And, Yes I am using a storyboard.

Comment: Check at [that image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5MLJH.png) where is the editable field

Comment: @MatthewHarris your problem is solved or not.

Comment: Thanks, My problem is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Storyboard via Interface Builder, and make sure that class is set the correct one (The Controller class on which you're trying to connect the outlet).

[image]

Comment: I have set the class of my UIViewController to UIViewController, so I don't know why this is happening

Comment: @MatthewHarris Set it to your custom class (which is inherited from UIViewController), as you can see I set it to GameViewController

Comment: you need to set the class on which you are trying to connect the outlet

Comment: aaah, I got it, you need to set "ViewController" type it exactly how I write (not UIViewController, you need to type ViewController)